# Add missing columns from different data.frame filled with 0

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following situation:

```
df1
a b c d
1 2 3 4

df2
a c
5 6
```

And the result I want is, to fill up the second data.frame with the missing columns from df1 and fill them with zeros. So the result should be:

```
df3
a b c d
5 0 6 0
```

The Data frames are quite big and that is why an automated way of doing this would be gerate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to find out columns which are not present in `df2` and assign the value 0 to those columns.

```
df2[setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))] <- 0

#  a c b d
#1 5 6 0 0
```

If we want to maintain the same order of columns as in `df1` we can later do

```
df2[names(df1)]
#  a b c d
#1 5 0 6 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but I think this works for your situation.
If you're not too fussed about mixing your workflow up with `dplyr` and `data.table` syntax, you can use `setdiff()` to identify non-matching column names, and use `data.table` syntax to create those zero-value columns efficiently without using loops or `apply()` functions. Once you've made sure this works for all the possible situations, you can wrap it in a function and scale this across more datasets.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 5, c = 6)

# Variables in df1 but not in df2
diff_vars <- dplyr::setdiff(names(df1),names(df2))

df2 %>%
  data.table::data.table() %>%
  .[,c(diff_vars):=0] %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() # Can choose to keep this in data.table
```

Comment: Just saw Ronak's post. I definitely over-complicated the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)

df2 <- data.frame(a = 5, c = 6)

library(tidyverse)

right_join(df1, df2)

 a  b c  d
1 5 NA 6 NA
```

You'll have to change NA's to 0.